# How Do I Use <input> to save the uploaded to a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn how to use the input upload tag to take audio files and play them.

In my HTML I have an input:

```
<h3>Upload Song: <input id="song" type="file" accept="audio/*" oninput="updateSong()"></input></h3>
```

The idea being that once the song is uploaded from the user's computer, the `updateSong()` function is called and and the system automatically saves the song as a var in javascript.

This would be done through the `updateSong()` function:

```
function updateSong(){
  song = document.getElementById("song");
  console.log(song)
  song.value.play();
}
var song;
```

Then, once the song is saved, I would like for the song to play - just as a test so I know it works.

However, when I use this code to execute my idea, I get the error:

```
TypeError: song.value.play is not a function
    at updateSong (/script.js:32:14)
    at HTMLInputElement.oninput (/:17:91)
```

What idea am I missing that is causing the code not to run? I established the song, and then update the variable with the song. This seems straightforward, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: `song` is an `<input>`, not a file. Can't play an `<input>`. Read up on how to read files and how to convert to dom elements

Comment: So type="file" doesn't tell the computer that it's a file?

Comment: No...it tells the browser it is an input that *accepts* files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file input has a [`files` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#files), which allows you to enumerate its list of files.

From there, you can use [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to create a temporary Blob-style object URL which references the file from the user's computer.

With that URL, you can instantiate a new [`Audio` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) and [start playback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play).  For example:

```
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.files);
  if (e.target.files.length) {
    const audio = new Audio(
      URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
    );
    audio.play();
  }
});
```

*(JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6tkxw0aj/)*

Don't forget to [revoke your object URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL) later when you're done with it!